CPU utilization in different monitoring apps
I noticed that when playing games such as Stalker 2, task manager reports loads of about 80-100% of the CPU while other monitoring apps like Nvidia App reports CPU loads of about 60-80%. Also, using HWinfo64, the CPU load is equivalent to Nvidia App.
I use the AMD Ryzen 5 7600 CPU, RTX4070 GPU, 32GB of RAM (dual channel), M.2 1TB PCI-e gen 4 SSD.
Which of the monitoring apps are reporting the real load of the CPU ?
I am asking this because I wanted to know if I need to upgrade the CPU.
Tried different monitoring apps, such as Nvidia App and HWinfo64.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question isn't about programming and would be better suited to Superuser on the Stack Exchange site. FWIW I wouldn't trust MS Task Manager to be accurate. You are allowed to use 100% of all CPUs although memory bandwidth usually chokes first. The chip just gets hotter at 100%. Sometimes it is worth avoiding using all available (virtual) CPUs since the thing can actually slow down if you push it beyond the sweet spot for memory IO bandwidth. It is worth experimenting with maximum number of active cores.
